# The semantic footer at the bottom of my page has space showing the background at the top and bottom of it. How do I get rid of this? Link below

Tags: css, html

If you scroll to the bottom of my page you'll see that there is space between the contact section and the footer then more space after the footer.  I know it's vague but I am new to this and can't figure out where it's coming from.

http://tommy2.bitballoon.com/

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Very odd indeed, Is this a WordPress site? Or a template? Or can you change the HTML?

Comment: No I made it with bootstrap.  I can change the HTML.  Would it be helpful to post my gist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This space is being caused by the default margin of the h1 in it. Just add some class and set margin-top to 0px on the h1.

Comment: You are awesome.  Thank You! One follow on question.  How can I get the footer not overlap with the background picture above?  I'd like to be able to see the boat in the picture when at the bottom of the page.

Comment: You can add "background-position: center bottom;" to the #contact div, so the bottom of the picture will always be shown, while the top will be cropped as needed to cover the div.

Answer (score 0):

You can mention margin-bottom to the contact section:

```
#contact {
  margin-bottom:-21px;
```

}

Comment: That's also a great suggestion thanks!  I went with Arton's answer though as they both work.  Maybe you can help with this though. How can I get the footer not overlap with the background picture above? I'd like to be able to see the boat in the picture when at the bottom of the page.

Comment: you can provide height to the img so that the boat is also visible while keeping the background-attachment fixed.You have to crop the image to a desirable height.

Comment: where would I add the height?

Comment: You have to crop the image in the img editor to the required height before using it as a background img.